# How to regenerate a complete config file from a kernel Image from buildroot

Tags: kernel, ethernet, buildroot

I have an `Image` that I generated using `buildroot` that boots a kernel from an SD card and it works perfectly.  I changed a few settings in the `buildroot` menus (I can't remember which ones) and now every `Image` that I generate no longer allows me to connect to the board through Ethernet after it boots, even though I am almost positive that I have reverted back to all of the settings in `buildroot` from before.

I have attempted to extract the `.config` file from the the perfect `Image` by moving the `/proc/config.gz` file to the SD card, extracting it, and then copying the `.config` to `/buildroot/output/build/linux-master/` directory and then running `make` from `/buildroot/` but that does not generate the same `Image` as the perfect one (I can tell right off the bat without even running it because the sizes are ~2MB different).

I also tried following the commands outlined in [this post](http://kbdatabase.org/article.php?id=17) (the part where it says to run the `extract-ikconfig`) but that just generated the same `.config` file as the first method - as to be expected.

Is there any other way that anyone knows to get back to the exact `buildroot` settings that were used to generate that perfect `Image`?  Or maybe know of some other reason for the `Connection refused` message I am getting when running the non-perfect `Image`?

Comment: Differenct compiler (gcc) versions produce different filesizes. Use the exactly same compilter and exactly same kernel version to produce same binaries. (But it is unnecessary - your system will be happy with bigger or smaller images.)

Comment: @IporSircer I have been using the exact same compiler every time.  So that is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I accidentally ran the wrong `make _defconfig` command from `/buildroot` directory so the `.config` at the top level had a different set of values than what I was expecting.  I ran the proper `make` command and am all set.